# FFmpeg - Fade in watermark only

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to place a watermark.png image on a video with a fade-in effect. This is my command:

> ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf movie=watermark_3.png, scale=144:31 [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=5:H-h-15, fade=in:0:30:alpha=1[out] -s 180x320 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy out.mp4

But this makes the whole video fade in from black.. Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 \
      -vf "movie=watermark_3.png:loop=0.1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale=144:31,format=rgba,fade=in:0:30:alpha=1[watermark]; \
           [in][watermark]overlay=5:H-h-15:shortest=1,scale=180x320[out]" \
      -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The fade has to be applied in the watermark chain to affect it only. The loop flag is set to a number below one, so that it loops the single image indefinitely. setpts ensures monotonically increasing timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that makes the watermark disappear :/ any ideas?

Comment: It fades out? Never appears?

Comment: It never appears. When i remove `fade=in:0:30:alpha=1` it appears, but without fade of course

Comment: Edited command.

Comment: It now stays in an infinite loop saying: `Incoming frame (time:24.8) from link #1 n:266.000000 t:8.856576 pos:161470.00000 x:10.000000 xi:10 y:145.000000 yi:144 *** dropping frame 268 from stream 0 at ts 266 Stream finished, looping.`

Comment: Added shortest flag.